# Dynamically generated <tr>s causing ASP.NET to crash

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

In ASP.NET MVC4 I am dynamically generating `<tr>`s in my table. I am doing this so I can apply different `onclick` values depending on a variable within the model.

When I do:

```
if(publication.ActionType == ActionType.NoticeOnly){
   <tr onclick='$launchMyEman(this, 'NoticeOnly')'>
} // Visual Studio treats this line as text, note code
```

So I use `Html.Encode()` as a work around. Here's my current code:

```
if(publication.ActionType == ActionType.NoticeOnly){
   @Html.Raw("<tr onclick='$launch(this, 'NoticeOnly')'>")
} else if (publication.ActionType == ActionType.ReadAndSign) {
   @Html.Raw("<tr onclick='$launch(this, 'ReadAndSign')'>")
} else {
   @Html.Raw("<tr onclick='$launch(this, 'ReadAndSignNotice')'>")
}
```

When this View is loaded, it causes the following error:

> Encountered end tag "tr" with no matching start tag.  Are your
>   start/end tags properly balanced?

The `</tr>` tag comes after a lot of `<td>`s. If I remove the code above and place a simple `<tr>` it works, so the error is definitely with the above code. When I place a breakpoint on the View, it never gets reached. It's at runtime.

Comment: See the view source for the rendered html and make sure you follow the standard HTML

Comment: I can't see the rendered HTML, all I get is a Parser Error page.

Comment: Encoding should be done when you literally want the <> characters displayed on the web page. You're trying to put down HTML, so you specifically do *not* want to encode.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I have tried with Html.Raw() and the same error occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change your code to the following:

```
@{
  string launchAction = string.Empty;
  switch (publication.ActionType)
  {
    case ActionType.NoticeOnly:
       launchAction = "NoticeOnly";
       break;
    case ActionType.ReadAndSign:
       launchAction = "ReadAndSign";
       break;
    default:
       launchAction = "ReadAndSignNotice";
       break;
  }
}
```

then you can just use the following html

```
<tr onclick="$launch(this, '@launchAction')">
```

Comment: Just thought of a similar solution myself. Thanks.

Comment: if your enum has 'ReadAndSignNotice' you could miss out the switch and just use `@publication.ActionType.ToString()`

Answer (score 1):

You are explicitly encoding your strings. What for? They will be rendered as `&lt;tr` - definitely not what you want.

You can use `Html.Raw` here to render the markup as is:

```
@Html.Raw("<tr onclick='$launch(this, 'NoticeOnly')'>")
```

Comment: @JohnSmith, there also might be a problem with the quotes - note that it's too many single quotes inside the string

Answer (score -1):

In your view try:

```
@if(publication.ActionType == ActionType.NoticeOnly){
   <tr onclick="$launch(this, 'NoticeOnly')">
} else if (publication.ActionType == ActionType.ReadAndSign) {
  <tr onclick="$launch(this, 'ReadAndSign')">
} else {
   <tr onclick="$launch(this, 'ReadAndSignNotice')">
}
```